# Jar resource files are missing when I build aar file

Tags: android, jar, android-gradle-plugin, resources, aar

I run into the following problem. I'm using gradle 4.1. I have Android Module which is packaged with the local jar file, the file is located under /libs folder and I use pretty standard way to include it

`implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

My problem is that the packaging process removes all resources folders from the jar file if my jar has ../resources/Messages.properties, in the aar it doesn't exist. It means that all messages are generated unproperly.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: AAR files include only the module sources, no libs/dependencies sources... You can try using a "Fat AAR" if you want to include dependencies and libs. You can also deploy your project as a maven artefact, the POM file include all the data needed to compile your project with everything. A 'local maven repo' might also be an option for you..

Comment: if I extract my aar file, it does contain folder 'libs' where all jars are located, the only problem, as I mentioned, these jars are different, they contain only classes, the other stuff just is filtered out.

Comment: Sorry dude, my answer is still the same.. AAR files can include only the module sources! No libs/dependencies sources. You may see the folder and the jar files.. but there will be no source code.. Tell me what you need the AAR for, maybe I can offer another alternative...

Comment: so if my jar dependancy has sources folder the aar packaging process just excludes them intentionally by modifying the original jar file and there is no way to control this process. The only a workaround comes to my mind is to copy these sources from jar to the module sources under appropriate package name?

Comment: 1) More or less, yes. 2) Theoretically that can work, but it's a lot of work, not scalable, and versioning will be an issue... Maybe those links would help: https://github.com/Vigi0303/fat-aar-plugin or https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar

Comment: you are correct there is a lot of maintenance overhead in my approach, I tried fat-aar-pluging, unfortunately, Android plugin version 2.3.0 and later is not well supported by fat-aar-pluging latest version